# Error when running initAudio

Tags: android, opensl, libpd

I've been building an android app that will output a single tone when opened (as a test for libpd), and I am encountering an error with OpenSL when I initialize and run PdService.initAudio and PdService.startAudio()

```
W/libOpenSLES: class OutputMix interface 0 requested but unavailable MPH=43
E/AudioTrack: AudioTrack::set : Exit
```

The speaker on the device turns on, and pops when I adjust the volume, but there is no audible tone.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share some of your code. Where you're trying to initialize the audio player

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am using libpd for android and opening a patch file and sending some message to audio controller. App plays the sound for 4-5 seconds and then crashes the app with 
W/libOpenSLES: class OutputMix interface 0 requested but unavailable MPH=43
E/AudioTrack: AudioTrack::set : Exit